# Internet Accounts in System Preferences has multiple entries for iCloud...why?

Tags: icloud, mojave, settings

The two that are active and the one that is inactive have the same email address gchung@me.com. Also, I cannot get rid of the Game Center account, which is also under gchung@me.com. I'm not sure what's going on here...

(edit: I've updated the images)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm inclined to leave things alone since everything seems to be working fine, but it is a little bit disconcerting.

Answer (score 1):

That's very unusual, perhaps you have two separate Apple ID accounts (and thus iCloud accounts). You can check this by clicking on each one and see what email address is listed on the right. Perhaps macOS allows you to login to the same iCloud account twice..

See if the checkmarks for what services are checked. If `Mail` is checked, see if you have multiple email accounts set up in the sidebar of your `Mail` application. If you don't but the mail checkmark is ticked on both accounts, it is pretty likely you can delete the duplicate account.

In theory, if they are the same account there would be no harm in deleting one of them by selecting one and clicking the delete "-" button at the bottom of that window. Although, I'm pretty sure some wise guy once said that if something works - don't touch it. Let me know how you go.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the original post. I only have one iCloud account on this laptop. But as you can see multiple iCloud entries in Internet Accounts. Also, I agree with you that I should probably just leave things be. (:

Comment: @triple.vee up to you, but I would leave it be :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have two iCloud accounts on my computer. You must be signed into iCloud with two different Apple IDs or have signed in with the same Apple ID twice. To remove an internet account, click on the account you want to remove and then click the minus (-) button.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the original post. I only have *one* iCloud account on this laptop. But as you can see multiple iCloud entries in Internet Accounts.

Comment: You must have signed in to the same account multiple times. I suggest you remove the last one and another one of your choosing. You shouldn't lose any information by doing so because all of the information in both accounts are the same.